# I want to get grand total of all users related to project using Laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to get grand total of all users and I have already got total of individual user but I need to get sum of all users related to project. I have no idea how to do that.

[image]

I want to get grand total like this:

```
Employee  | joylinkhk | merakpaper 

azher     |   7       |  8
usaid     |   2       |  9

Grand     |   9       | 17  
total
```

**html view**

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table table-responsive" >
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Employee
                  </th>
                  @foreach($projects as  $project)  
                  <th>{{$project->name}}
                  </th>
                  @endforeach
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                @foreach ($hourlogs->groupBy("user_id") as $item)
                    <tr>
                      <td>{{$item->first()->user->name}}</td>
                      @foreach($projects as  $project)  
                        <td>{{round($item->where("project_id", $project->id)->sum("hour_work") / 60,1)}}</td>
                      @endforeach
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
              </tbody>
              <tfoot>
                 <tr>
                  <td>Grand Total</td>  
                     
                    <td></td>
                     
                </tr>
              </tfoot>
            </table>
```

Comment: Instead you should send the sum from controller itself. Controller is used to write all the business logic, view is just to show. It will be faster, less data to send.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why wouldn't a simple `sum()` method solve the issue?

```
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <td>Grand Total</td>  
        @foreach($projects as $project) 
        <td>{{round($hourlogs->where('project_id', $project->id)->sum('hour_work') / 60, 1)}}</td>
        @endforeach
    </tr>
</tfoot>
```

This way you're simply filtering the `Hourlog` instances for each project and summing their `hour_work` for all users.